# tf MUX (or multiple-parents)

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running up against a wall in the form of tf's tree restrictions.  Namely, I'd like to have both gmapping and amcl running simultaneously (long story), but both publish XXX => odom_combined (naturally, the parent frame is param-configurable).  The problem is, that tf (apparently) does not allow multiple parents (eg. it forces it to be a tree), and there doesn't seem to be a way to flip the directionality of the transform (odom_combined => XXX).

I thought perhaps tf_remap or tf_prefix would fit the bill... but after a few hours of experimentation, both approaches still end up in this same problem.  I guess... what I'm really looking for is something akin to topic_tools/mux only for tf topics.  Then I could just flip the mux when I want one transform or another.

Has anyone found a good solution to this sort of problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9406/tf-mux-(or-multiple-parents)/) by [Travis Deyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/287/travis-deyle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately keeping two copies of the sate is not something which the system was designed for.

I have two work arounds, a selective relay or inverting one of the transforms.

I'll start with inverting one of the transforms.  To allow multiple odometry frames for a while we would publish the the odom frame as a child instead of a parent, such that it would not conflict with the "odom_combined" frame.  To do this you could either modify gmapping or amcl to publish with a different frame_id as a child instead of as a parent.  This will provide both frames in a running system but with different names.

If you want to be able to swap them while running I believe what you will need is a selective relay.  It will need to listen to the caller_id and forward all messages from /tf to /other_tf except those originating from the localization node on /other_tf.  And have a node which is passing back the localization information on /other_tf and pass it back on /tf.  You can then turn on and off the pass back capability.  To do this you will need a version of relay which relays all messages execept for ones with a specific caller id.  And a 2nd one which only forwards a specific caller_id.  If you end up doing this I'd suggest providing patches to topic_tools relay/mux which add these as parameters if possible.  I'm sure others would find it useful too.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-09-28**:
man, you are a genius. I mean, with such a limitation, TF is pretty bad, because a node should be allowed to have multiple parents, but this trick is a great workaround.